# world image texture in the viewport is different from the render

Tags: rendering, world, texture-coordinates

For the same frame, I show my viewport and rendered image. They are different. [image]

The world texture is not rotated correctly. I think it might be the rotation value around the Z-axis is not implemented during rendering but I'm not sure if this is the reason or not so this is my world material:
[image]

Comment: is the gray background part of your image?

Comment: Yesss, it is. Just a different rotation.

Comment: could you please pack the image and share the file? (delete all the useless objects)

Comment: I'm so sorry to bother you. When I deleted everything, the issue is resolved. I inspected again and I found a very big Icosphere that I previously made. It surrounds my scene and It has the same image. I hid it from the viewport but I forgot to hide it from render. Sorry again :)

Comment: ah ah nice then   ;)